# Xcode 3.2 fonts are too bold on dark backgrounds

Tags: xcode, fonts, themes

I just upgraded from Xcode 3.1.4 to 3.2.1. Previously I've been using the Dusk color theme. After the upgrade I noticed that the fonts on this theme seem much bolder that for other default themes, even though they all use the same font type and size (Menlo Regular - 11). It seems that Xcode makes the font a little wider as you change the background to darker colors. This is simply annoying.

Has anyone noticed this? I can't find a way to use normal looking fonts on a dark background...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try Monaco - 12 on a dark background, I think the appearance of fonts on a dark background is probably an OS thing to do with how Mac OSX antialiases fonts

Comment: OK, disabled font smoothing from System Preferences/Appearance and set the font to Monaco - 10. This seems to look like the original Dusk theme on the old Xcode on Leopard.